# Perform a search navigating a relationship between 2 models in Kohana

Tags: orm, model, kohana, relationship

Let's say I have 2 models user and location. There is a defined relationship between the models that allows me to do this:

```
$user->location->name;
```

I don't know if it's possible but can I perform a search using something like:

```
$user->location->where('name', '=', 'Paris')->find();
```

that returns me the users that its location is named Paris?

Answer (score 2):

In short you can. Here is why.

When you call the `find` method the ORM goes through all of the pending properties to be added to the query, adds them and executes the query. In your example you have two pending rules to be added to your query. The first one you are defining obviously - `where('name', '=', 'Paris')`, the second one is hidden in the relationship `$user->location`.

When you call an ORM property from a relationship, it actually returns an ORM object defined in the relationship which is not loaded, but has a pending `where` clause and a `join` in its object. So when you call the `find` method in the end, you are calling it on the location object with two `where` clauses and one `join`.